# How to print out an element from a JavaScript array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have this array, how I can print out an element inside it?

For example, I want to print out, inside a new "div", the number "4" of "Date" and the text "descrizione descrizione" of "Title".

to create a new "div" I have used: *document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(div);*

```js
// EVENT MANAGER

var events = [
  {'Date': new Date(2017, 5, 4), 'Title': 'descrizione descrizione'},
  {'Date': new Date(2017, 5, 18), 'Title': 'desrizione descrizione', 'Link': 'www.google.com'},
  {'Date': new Date(2017, 6, 27), 'Title': 'descrizione descrizione'},
  {'Date': new Date(2017, 6, 28), 'Title': 'descrizione descrizione'},
  {'Date': new Date(2017, 6, 29), 'Title': 'descrizione descrizione'},
  {'Date': new Date(2017, 6, 10), 'Title': 'descrizione descrizione'},
  {'Date': new Date(2017, 6, 22), 'Title': 'descrizione descrizione'},
];

var settings = {};
var element = document.getElementById('caleandar');
caleandar(element, events, settings);
```

Thanks

EDIT: Thanks ALL

Comment: I've edited the term JSON out of your question, since your question has absolutely nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: Ok thanks. and sorry for mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

.JS:

```
// EVENT MANAGER

var events = [
  {'Date': new Date(2017, 5, 4), 'Title': 'descrizione descrizione'},
  {'Date': new Date(2017, 5, 18), 'Title': 'desrizione descrizione', 'Link': 'www.google.com'},
  {'Date': new Date(2017, 6, 27), 'Title': 'descrizione descrizione'},
  {'Date': new Date(2017, 6, 28), 'Title': 'descrizione descrizione'},
  {'Date': new Date(2017, 6, 29), 'Title': 'descrizione descrizione'},
  {'Date': new Date(2017, 6, 10), 'Title': 'descrizione descrizione'},
  {'Date': new Date(2017, 6, 22), 'Title': 'descrizione descrizione'},
];

document.getElementById("calendar").append("Day:  "+events[0].Date.getDate()+" ; Title: "+events[0].Title)
```

Comment: This is perfectly works, can I ".append" another value when I click another element? I have a calendar and I need to "append" different values at different "divs"... thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes, you can make a js function like this in which you pass the value from the html, like: **HTML:** <button onclick="appendDate('number of events index')">Append</button> 
**JS:** var appendDate = function(i){
  document.getElementById("calendar").append("<div>Day:  "+events[i].Date.getDate()+" ; Title: "+events[i].Title+"</div>")
}

Answer (score 1):

```
// Using forEach loop    
function(events) {
    events.forEach(function(event) {
        console.log(event.Date);
        console.log(event.Title);
    });
}
```

Comment: ok, only one thing... its says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ("

Answer (score 0):

create the DOM node and add the content to it's innerHTML

```
events.forEach(function(event){
    var divToAdd = document.createElement('div');
    divToAdd.innerHTML = event.Date.getDate() + " - " + event.Title;
    document.body.appendChild(divToAdd);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a foreach-loop on the array, to create the divs with the content and to append it to the body.
You can use the day accessor of a Date object to get the day. See documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
events.forEach(function(event){
 var day = String(event.Date.day);
 var title = event.Title;

 var div = document.createElement("div");
 div.innerHTML = day+" - "+title;
 body.appendChild(div);
});
```